# Microsoft Project Server 2019 Event Receiver

Tags: event-receivers, project-server

Can anyone help and share with me the article or blog link to create an **Event Receiver in Project Server 2019 on-prem environment**. I found some articles based on 2010/2013, which I tried but not working properly.

**Scenario:**
Need to update the **Project Owner** field on Project Published or Saved?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this Microsoft article:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/gg615466(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN